# String with Multiple delimiters- MySQL Insert row by row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am inserting string with multiple delimiters and split it using explode function to mysql database table but i failed in building proper logic.

I tried with single delimiter i-e , and successfully insert that record.
        Now i want to split string with | and ,.
 I used for row separation and `|` for value seperation.
i-e
 `$var = "Facebook|http://facebook.com/123|12312|12` to `13,Twitter|http://twitter.com/231|12321|12 to 13";`

```
$cat="2,3";
$i=0;
$arrayOfCategories = explode(",", $cat);
foreach ($arrayOfCategories as $categories) {
    $datas[$i]['UserID'] = 2;
    $datas[$i]['CatID'] = $categories;
    $i++;
}
var_dump($datas);
```

Format showed using `var_dump` is the format which i want to insert using insert_batch of codeigniter.

This is the expected output

```
   array (size=2) 
    0 => array (size=2) 
        'SocialName' => string 'Facebook' 
        'URL' => string 'facebook.com/123' 
    1 => array (size=2) 
        'SocialName' => string 'Twitter' 
        'URL' => string 'twitter.com/231'
```

Comment: I think you will have to show us the expected output for us to be able to understand what you now want to do

Comment: You can use `preg_split` for this, see sample code : `$d = preg_split( "/[|,]+/" , 'Facebook|http://facebook.com/123|12312|12 to 13,Twitter|http://twitter.com/231|12321|12 to 13');
print_r($d);` Output: `Array ( [0] => Facebook [1] => http://facebook.com/123 [2] => 12312 [3] => 12 to 13 [4] => Twitter [5] => http://twitter.com/231 [6] => 12321 [7] => 12 to 13 )`

Comment: Iwant to achieve this structure of my array:                                                  array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'SocialName' => string 'Facebook'
      'URL' => string 'http://facebook.com/123'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
    'SocialName' => string 'Twitter'
      'URL' => string 'http://twitter.com/231'

Comment: It is always better to add this into your question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$string = "Facebook|http://facebook.com/123|12312|12 to 13,Twitter|http://twitter.com/231|12321|12 to 13";

$rows = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $values = explode('|', $row);
    $array[] = array('SocialName' => $values[0], 'URL' => $values[1]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Create an array `$array` to store the final result in.

Now, split the input string `$string` on `,` using explode, this gives you the "rows".

Go through all the rows (foreach), and split each row on the `|` (explode), this gives you the "values".

The first value `$values[0]` is the "SocialName", and the second value `$values[1]` is the "URL", so add those to a new array, and add that new array to the final result array `$array`.